# Add reference field to the context of a view

Tags: odoo, odoo-8

I have a reference field in a model

```
ref = fields.Reference ....
```

I added it to the search view of a treeview, And when I try to add this field to a context to open the view with `search_default_ref:'sale.order,1'`, it's ignored and not added to the search field.

Answer (score 1):

That string must match the Reference field content:

```
{'search_default_ref': 'SO0001'}
```

If you want to search on the record id you should use:

```
{'search_default_id': 1}
```

Or better yet,  use the corresponding XML Id, such as:

```
{'search_default_id': ref('sale.sale_order_1')}
```

Comment: It shows me this error:
Odoo Client Error
Uncaught TypeError: callable.__call__ is not a function
http://127.0.0.1:8065/web/static/lib/py.js/lib/py.js:569

Comment: Here is an example usage in the core addons: https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/9.0/addons/hr_payroll/res_config_view.xml#L8

Comment: in this example, the type 'category_id' is many2one not reference, I didn't find an exmaple of my case.